# How can I set start point for ALS recommender in spark mlib?

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine

I am using this code to get ALS recommendations:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("SomeAppName")
        .config("spark.master", "local")
        .getOrCreate();
JavaRDD<Rating> ratingsRDD = spark
        .read().textFile(args[0]).javaRDD()
        .map(Rating::parseRating);
Dataset<Row> ratings = spark.createDataFrame(ratingsRDD, Rating.class);
ALS als = new ALS()
        .setMaxIter(1)
        .setRegParam(0.01)
        .setUserCol("userId")
        .setItemCol("movieId")
        .setRatingCol("rating");
ALSModel model = als.fit(ratings);
model.setColdStartStrategy("drop");
Dataset<Row> rowDataset = model.recommendForAllUsers(50);
```

I want to reuse feature vectors for users and items from previous run. How can I set these values as initial point?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save time and skip training step each time you run the app, you can simply save trained als with:

`model.save(jsc.sc(), "saved_model");`

and load it in another script.

More info here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html

Comment: I don't want to load model. I want to train it using previous parameters as initial point.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'initial point'? you can not immediately start training ALS without spark session or without loading the data.

Comment: Training is adjusting coefficients in the model: user and item features. in ALS.scala these items are initialized by random noise, i want to initialize them somehow else.